# Relationship not being applied correctly between nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, family-tree

I am trying to run the code on [this GraphGist](http://neo4j.com/graphgist/11337934/) to play with the Buendia Family Tree in Neo4j.

When I create two nodes and try to connect them with a relationship, as such:

```
CREATE (JoseArcadioBuendia:Male {name:'Jose Arcadio Buendia',Gender:'Male'})
```

then

```
CREATE (UrsulaIguaran:Female {name:'Ursula Iguaran',Gender:'Female'})
```

then

```
CREATE (JoseArcadioBuendia)-[:HUSBAND]->(UrsulaIguaran)
```

I get this:

[image]

Why is this code incorrect?  The syntax looks fine and it appears to run for the author of the Gist. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: the query works for me. I just did copy paste and ran it. it works ..

Comment: yes, cybersam cleared it up -- identifiers only exist for the life of a single query. I had done entry line by line.

Comment: Got it . I was wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you did not include all 3 `CREATE` clauses in a single query.

Cypher identifiers (like `JoseArcadioBuendia` and `UrsulaIguaran`) only exist for the life of a single query. The DB does not persist these identifiers. So, if you have a query that contains just `CREATE (JoseArcadioBuendia)-[:HUSBAND]->(UrsulaIguaran)`), neo4j would not know that the nodes already exist and would therefore create 2 new nodes for you (as well as the relationship).

If you had put all 3 clauses in a single query, you would have seen the results you expected. Otherwise, your query would first have to use `MATCH` to associate those identifiers with the proper nodes (similar to @Bond's answer).

Comment: ah! I see! So I guess you could say that the problem ultimately comes down to me using the web interface and not the terminal.

Comment: Actually, you can use multi-clause queries in the neo4j browser.

Answer (score 0):

The third line is incorrect. You are not specifying any nodes. Try the following:

```
MATCH (a:Male), (b:Female)
WHERE a.name = 'Jose Arcadio Buendia' AND b.name = 'Ursula Iguaran'
CREATE (a)-[:HUSBAND]->(b);
```

Comment: I get `A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE (line 3, column 11 (offset: 104))`

Comment: I have edited @Bond's answer to make `HUSBAND` a relationship type (by adding the ":" prefix), and to fix Ursala's name.